# get count of a user's mentions in a channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to count the amount of times a user has been mentioned in a channel. The code I have is:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch()
    .then(messages => console.log(`${messages.filter(m => m.mentions.users[1] === 'msg.author').size} messages`))
    .catch(console.error);
```

When I ran this in a channel I had 27 mentions in that channel's history. This returned `0 messages`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is with your filter,

`m.mentions.users` is a collection mapped by the users id, when you do [1] it checks for a user with the id of 1 and then checks it to the string `msg.author`

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch()
 .then(messages => {
   //.has() checks if the collection includes the key
   const size = messages.filter(m => m.mentions.users.has(message.author.id)).size;
   console.log(size, "messages");
});
 .catch(console.error);
```